# jqplot is using a different y scale for each series in a stacked barchart

Tags: jqplot

[image]

I am using jqplot, why is the stacked barchart using a different Y scale for each series?

```
var ticks = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9"];
var s1 = ["3", "3", "1", "3", "2", "3", "30", "3", "3"];
var s2 = ["0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];

      plot3 = $.jqplot('daily-bookings-by-user', [s1, s2], {
        // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
        stackSeries: true,
        seriesDefaults:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
          rendererOptions: {
              // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
              barMargin: 20,
              // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
              // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
              highlightMouseDown: true
          },
          pointLabels: {show: true}
        },
        axes: {
          xaxis: {
              renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
              ticks: ticks
          },
          yaxis: {
            // Don't pad out the bottom of the data range.  By default,
            // axes scaled as if data extended 10% above and below the
            // actual range to prevent data points right on grid boundaries.
            // Don't want to do that here.
            padMin: 0,
            pad: 0,
            min: 0,
          },
        },
        legend: {
          show: true,
          location: 'e',
          placement: 'outside'
        },
        series:[
            {
               label:'Test 1'
            },
            {
               label:'Test 2'
            }
        ],
      });
```

Comment: I can't get the image to upload sorry.  It just displays as a grey square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happeneing because you are passing in the data as `string`.
so when you stack the bar, the logic add up both the values to show the stacked bar.
but in your case "1" and "2", they get concatenated because you are passing them in as strings to form "21", which is then converted into integer to plot. Thats why you see 21 getting plotted.

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cLbtx/1/)

```
var s1 = [3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 30, 3, 3];
var s2 = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

This would fix your problem.

Comment: Good spotting, cheers. Actually the original data was coming from a json datasource so I suppose I just assumed they were numeric.